# Group array of objects by category

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

How can I group this array of objects by `categoria`?

```
items = [
  { categoria: 'Sandwiches', nombre: 'Sandwich de Pollo',  precio: 12 },
  { categoria: 'Sandwiches', nombre: 'Sandwich de Lomo',  precio: 12 },
  { categoria: 'Helados', nombre: 'Helado de 1 bola', precio: 5 },
  { categoria: 'Helados', nombre: 'Helado de 2 bolas', precio: 8 },
  { categoria: 'Helados', nombre: 'Helado de 3 bolas', precio: 10 },
];
```

I want to get is something like this, I'm working on Typescript with Angular:

```
itemsResult = [
{
  categoria: 'Sandwiches',
  items: [
    { nombre: 'Sandwich de Pollo',  precio: 12 },
    { nombre: 'Sandwich de Lomo',  precio: 12 },
  ]
},
{
  categoria: 'Helados',
  items: [
    { nombre: 'Helado de 1 bola', precio: 5 },
    { nombre: 'Helado de 2 bolas', precio: 8 },
    { nombre: 'Helado de 3 bolas', precio: 10 },
  ]
 },
];
```

I have tried with a `reduce` but what I get is an object, I want an array

```
this.itemsGroup = this.items.reduce((r, a) => {
      r[a.categoria] = r[a.categoria] || [];
      r[a.categoria].push(a);
      return r;
    }, Object.create(null));
    console.log(this.itemsGroup);

{
  Sandwiches: [
   { nombre: 'Sandwich de Pollo',  precio: 12 },
   { nombre: 'Sandwich de Pollo',  precio: 15 }
  ],
  Helados: [
   { nombre: 'Helado de 1 bola', precio: 5 },
   { nombre: 'Helado de 2 bolas', precio: 8 },
   { nombre: 'Helado de 3 bolas', precio: 10 }
  ]
}
```

Comment: i also had a somewhat similar question but in js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69718500/change-structure-of-array-of-objects-to-desired-format

Comment: your implementation isnt bad . you can access everything

Comment: How do I access that implementation?

Comment: if your final result from reduce is an object say `a`. then can access each category like `a['categoryName']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [_.groupBy()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/underscore-js-_-groupby-function/)

```
const items = [
  { categoria: 'Sandwiches', nombre: 'Sandwich de Pollo', precio: 12 },
  { categoria: 'Sandwiches', nombre: 'Sandwich de Lomo', precio: 12 },
  { categoria: 'Helados', nombre: 'Helado de 1 bola', precio: 5 },
  { categoria: 'Helados', nombre: 'Helado de 2 bolas', precio: 8 },
  { categoria: 'Helados', nombre: 'Helado de 3 bolas', precio: 10 },
];

let newArr = [];
let grp = _.groupBy(items, "categoria");

for (const obj in grp) {
  newArr.push({ categoria: obj, items: grp[obj] });
}

console.log(newArr, 'newArr');
```

If you don't want to `underscore.js` you can do it using `reduce()` !

```
const items = [
  { categoria: 'Sandwiches', nombre: 'Sandwich de Pollo', precio: 12 },
  { categoria: 'Sandwiches', nombre: 'Sandwich de Lomo', precio: 12 },
  { categoria: 'Helados', nombre: 'Helado de 1 bola', precio: 5 },
  { categoria: 'Helados', nombre: 'Helado de 2 bolas', precio: 8 },
  { categoria: 'Helados', nombre: 'Helado de 3 bolas', precio: 10 },
];
let newArr = [];

let grp = items.reduce((group, product) => {
  const { categoria } = product;
  group[categoria] = group[categoria] ?? [];
  group[categoria].push(product);
  return group;
}, {});

for (const obj in grp) {
  newArr.push({ categoria: obj, items: grp[obj] });
}

console.log(newArr, 'newArr');
```

Comment: but need external dependancy underscore for this

Comment: Yes , you need the `underscore.js`

Comment: i dont think it is a good answer if he doesn't specifically mentioned using underscore or lodash. maybe you can add a pure js/ts as well

Comment: @Paco Zevallos  I update my answer pls check !

Comment: @MayurVaghasiya this worked great for me, thanks.

Comment: Hey @MayurVaghasiya, check my solution. I think it may be of interest to you because in the reduce I don't set object value by default, but an array

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```js
const items = [
  { categoria: "Sandwiches", nombre: "Sandwich de Pollo", precio: 12 },
  { categoria: "Sandwiches", nombre: "Sandwich de Lomo", precio: 12 },
  { categoria: "Helados", nombre: "Helado de 1 bola", precio: 5 },
  { categoria: "Helados", nombre: "Helado de 2 bolas", precio: 8 },
  { categoria: "Helados", nombre: "Helado de 3 bolas", precio: 10 }
];

const groupedArr = items.reduce((prev, { categoria, ...items }) => {
  const id = prev.findIndex((item) => item.categoria === categoria);
  id >= 0 
    ? prev[id].items.push(items)
    : prev.push({categoria, items: [items]})
  return prev
}, []);

console.log(groupedArr);
```

I think it is more clearable and shorted than @MayurVaghasiya solution.

Additionally, it doesn't need any dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @Kordrad this had an advantage over the accepted solution (with for loop). This allows me to update the data in real time.